# JavaScript cannot get onmousemove script to work as intended

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I have a function to follow the object after the mouse,
and I want to be able to stop and start following at will, without hiding the object.

It almost works as I wanted, and is following the mouse indeed, but I cannot make it move initial position without actually moving the mouse.

E.G. When I trigger the function, the object is still somewhere in another place, until I move the mouse, but what I'm trying to do is to move it the initial position first, before attaching the `mousemove` event.

Here is how I want to trigger the function:

```
showtrail();

function showtrail(shit){
//this is how I tried to set the initial position first, but this get me an error:..
//followmouse(); 
document.onmousemove=followmouse; //and this is how I attach the event.
}
```

This is a part of the actual function to move the object,
but, I can't get the coordinates if I try to initilize/imitate the first movement.

```
    function followmouse(e){
var xcoord=offsetfrommouse[0]
var ycoord=offsetfrommouse[1]
if (typeof e != "undefined"){  //This- if triggered by mousemove, and it works
xcoord+=e.pageX
ycoord+=e.pageY
}
else {   //this was meant for the initial call, but... for some reason
xcoord+=document.body.scrollLeft+event.clientX // it triggers an error,
ycoord+=document.body.scrollTop+event.clientY // saying event.clientX undefined.
}
}
```

So the `event.clientX` never seems to work, and I cannot figure out how to get the actual mouse position otherwise..

Please guide..

Comment: `e` is undefined because you don't pass it into your function. Also, you magically renamed `e` to `event` in the second part of the `if `statement.

Comment: e was not supposed to be passed manually, but it is passed automatically by mousemove event. 'event' is a shortcut for the window.event I think.

Comment: Exactly. When you call `followmouse();`, it isn't passed in. What event should `event` refer to?

Comment: I don't know how to pass the event position. It is being triggered by hoverintent, and returns an event with position on the edge. By that time the mouse already moved so it results in a wierd behaviour

Comment: `event.clientX` returns undefined because the event is of type `load` due to which it does not have the property `clientX`. I am not aware of a way to get the mouse co-ordinates before the mouse has moved. Your best option is to capture it when it first moves.

Comment: As I know you cannot get mouse coordinates outside of mouse events. Can you add more description about conditions of executing `showtrail()` function: focusing or bluring some elements, keyboards inputs? When `showtrail()` is executed and where `offsetfrommouse` content writed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright that's how I done it.
The best Idea was to always capture a move to set position in a global var.
Now I have an option to display it fixed at any specific place (if I pass coords to showtrail)
or to actually follow the mouse;
I also added an event listener, so if the mouse gets outside the window while following- it will be hidden.
So far it works exactly as I wanted:

```
var trailimage=["scripts/loading_mouse.gif", 24, 24] //image path, plus width and height
var offsetfrommouse=[2,10] //image x,y offsets from cursor position in pixels. Enter 0,0 for no offset
var global_coord=[0,0]
var follow=false;

if (document.getElementById || document.all)
document.write('<div id="trailimageid" style="z-index: 10;position:absolute;display:none;left:0px;top:0px;width:1px;height:1px"><img src="'+trailimage[0]+'" border="0" width="'+trailimage[1]+'px" height="'+trailimage[2]+'px"></div>')

function gettrailobj(){
if (document.getElementById)
return document.getElementById("trailimageid").style
else if (document.all)
return document.all.trailimagid.style
}

function hidett(){  gettrailobj().display="none";   }
function showtt(){  gettrailobj().display="block";  }

function truebody(){    return (document.body||document.documentElement);   }

function showtrail(shit){
    if (typeof shit == "undefined"){    //Follow Mouse
        follow=true;
        setmousepos(global_coord[0],global_coord[1]);
    }
    else {              //Set fixed in specific place
        follow=false;
        showtt()
        gettrailobj().left=shit.left+6+"px"
        gettrailobj().top=shit.top-5+"px"
    }
}

function hidetrail(){
    hidett()
    follow=false;
}

function setcoord(e){
var xcoord=offsetfrommouse[0]
var ycoord=offsetfrommouse[1]
var xxcoord = e.pageX||(e.clientX+truebody().scrollLeft);
var yycoord = e.pageY||(e.clientY+truebody().scrollTop);
if (typeof xxcoord != "undefined"&&typeof yycoord != "undefined"){
    xcoord+=xxcoord;
    ycoord+=yycoord;
    global_coord=[xcoord,ycoord];
    if (follow) setmousepos(xcoord,ycoord);
}}

function setmousepos(xcoord,ycoord){
    var docwidth=truebody().scrollLeft+truebody().clientWidth   
    var docheight=Math.max(truebody().scrollHeight, truebody().clientHeight)
    if ((xcoord+trailimage[1]+3>docwidth || ycoord+trailimage[2]> docheight ||!follow)){
        hidett()
    }
    else{
        showtt();
        gettrailobj().left=xcoord+"px"
        gettrailobj().top=ycoord+"px"
    }
}

window.addEventListener("mouseout",
    function(e){
        mouseX = e.pageX;
        mouseY = e.pageY;
        if ((mouseY >= 0 && mouseY <= window.innerHeight)
        && (mouseX >= 0 && mouseX <= window.innerWidth)){
            return false;
        }else{
            if (follow) hidett()
        }
    },
    false);

document.onmousemove=setcoord;
```

Answer (score 0):

event.clientX and event.clientY are wrong. They should be e.clientX and e.clientY

A more elegant cross browser way to get xcoord and ycoord in followmouse(e) is:

```
xcoord = e.pageX||(e.clientX+(document.body.scrollLeft||document.documentElement.scrollLeft));
ycoord = e.pageY||(e.clientY+(document.body.scrollTop||document.documentElement.scrollTop));
```

Now if I'm getting it right, the object that follows is expected to have an initial absolute position and displayed as a block, meaning that you have initial x and y (left and top). Therefore by using a global bool var for currently following or not you're done.

```
<style>
...
#trail {position:absolute;left:0;top:0;display:none}
...
</style>

<script>
var following = false;
...
function followmouse(e){
   if (!following){
       document.getElementById('trail').style.display='none';
       return;
   }
   ...
   document.getElementById('trail').style.display='block';
}
</script>
```

By changing display you have the option to move your #trail to its initial position and then follow the mouse, and the option to avoid the move and let it follow the mouse from its latest following position.

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT 1:***

For this very purpose, I recommend using of [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame) API, not classic DOM events. said API is more efficient for creating animations and pausing them.

take a look at this too: [requestAnimationFrame for smart animating](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/)

---

This is sad, but true that you can not get mouse's initial position before moving mouse on a webpage. I mean you can't calibrate your object before `mousemove` event. this is what I will do in a similar project:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var targetID = 'mydiv'; // div that is to follow the mouse
            var pauseFollowing = false;
            // (must be position:absolute)
            var offX = 15;          // X offset from mouse position
            var offY = 15;          // Y offset from mouse position

            function mouseX(evt) {if (!evt) evt = window.event; if (evt.pageX) return evt.pageX; else if (evt.clientX)return evt.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ?  document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft); else return 0;}
            function mouseY(evt) {if (!evt) evt = window.event; if (evt.pageY) return evt.pageY; else if (evt.clientY)return evt.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop); else return 0;}

            function follow(evt) {
                if(pauseFollowing) {
                    //or do something else at pause
                    return false;
                }
                var obj = document.getElementById(targetID).style;
                obj.visibility = 'visible';
                obj.left = (parseInt(mouseX(evt))+offX) + 'px';
                obj.top = (parseInt(mouseY(evt))+offY) + 'px';
            }

            function toggleFollow() {
                pauseFollowing = !pauseFollowing;
            }

            window.onload = function() {
                window.onclick = toggleFollow;
                document.onmousemove = follow;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mydiv" style="visibility: hidden; top:0; left:0 ;width: 100px; height: 100px; background: #ff0; position: absolute;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```